# How do I get the last refresh date/time from a query?

Tags: excel, vba, connection, refresh

I have a workbook with a multiple queries from an SQL database and wanted to get the last refreshed date/time as either a variable in VBA or written to a cell in the workbook.

I tried this code:

```
Cells(1,1) = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Item_Groups").ODBCConnection.RefreshDate
```

But I get I get an Application Defined or Object Defined error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it actually an ODBCConnection? What does `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Item_Groups").Type` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: it just gives me a "1" I tried OLEDBConnection too I cant seem to get anything that will produce a RefreshDate

Comment: `1` corresponds to `xlConnectionTypeOLEDB` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlconnectiontype). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727363/oledb-connection-has-no-refresh-date) might also be useful.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen! the solutions in that link should get me what I need!